# How to connect USB led strip via battery

Tags: led-strip

I got a USB led strip from Ebay. Unfortunately there is no indication what type of led it is. Looking at power converter it says "5V Output 3x2A"

One strip has 15 leds. I want to connect it via standard battery (9V but if 3xAA are better they I am open to that.)

Also I wanted to add 3 potentiometers to be able to control each color separately. 
I did this on my Arduino - connected 3 10k Potentiometers and it kinda works but the knobs are not linear so I get full power when "open" and if I just "close" is a bit it loses like 50% power.

Not sure what's the best circuit I should build to make this work.

Any advice would be helpful.

Pictures attached for reference.

[image: LED Stripe]
[image: USB Power Adapter]

Comment: Scrap it and buy a unit that comes with proper documentation.

Comment: Great advise, thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use this continually, I suggest to use a buck converter along your 9v battery. Buck converters will reduce your input voltage to a level that is interesting to you. In this case, 5V. 
The other thing that makes me think that this is a interesting option is the fact that the potentiometer used to variate between voltages on the buck converter is prepared to this application, in a way that it will have small currents flowing on its terminals.
Using a potentiometer in series of your voltage source will not be a good idea, since all the system current will be flowing on it and the current for the normal potentiometers is low.